# Client doesn't "onconnect" to Socket.io, but throws error when server is closed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I am in the process of moving a socket.io/node.js server from my local machine to a digitalocean vpn, but I am experiencing some strange connection issues.

I don't see any errors thrown when I try to connect, but the 'connection' event isn't fired on client or server side.

However, if I close the server, I get this error on client side: `GET http://myip:8000/socket.io/1/?t=1410475126223 net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

So it seems that it is actually connecting, just not firing any events?

Here is my server side code:

```
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(8000);
io = require("socket.io").listen(server);
io.sockets.on("connection", onSocketConnection);
```

and client side:

```
socket = io.connect("104.131.41.120", {port: 8000});
socket.on("connect", onSocketConnection);
```

Comment: What do you see on the network tab?

Comment: any errors being thrown in the browser console log?

Comment: No errors in the console.

Comment: In the Network tab, I see the path to my server is "(pending)"

Comment: But if I stop the server, the status immediately changes to "(failed) net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"